# PHP-Oauth authentication with Grant CodeFlow

Tags: php, curl, post, oauth, request

I implement  OAUTH authentication. I'm sending a POST request to an API. But something is wrong in my code. I get error 404 back. can someone help me. this API does not support ClientSecret.
this is my Code

```html
<?php

$callback_uri  =  "http://localhost/zeiterfassung/" ;

$client_id  =  "2371031349-3075189699-483870032-1896673008" ;

$code = $_GET['code'];

$resourc = "http://localhost/zeiterfassung/";

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    // try to get an access token
    $code = $_GET['code'];
    $url = 'https://adfs3int.fds.metro.info/oauth2/token';
    $params = array(
        "code" => $code,
        "client_id" => $client_id,
        "redirect_uri" => 'http://' . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"],
        "grant_type" => "authorization_code"
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, constant("CURLOPT_" . 'URL'), $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, constant("CURLOPT_" . 'POST'), true);
    curl_setopt($ch, constant("CURLOPT_" . 'POSTFIELDS'), $params);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    if ($info['http_code'] === 200) {
        header('Content-Type: ' . $info['content_type']);
        return $output;
    } else {
        return 'An error happened';
    }

} else {

    $url = "https://adfs3int.fds.metro.info/adfs/oauth2/authorize";

    $params = array(
        "response_type" => "code",
        "client_id" => $client_id,
        "redirect_uri" => $callback_uri,
        "resource" => $resourc
    );

    $request_to = $url . '?' . http_build_query($params);

    header("Location: " . $request_to);
}
?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

404 is a client site error and say's that you have done something wrong - it means that what you are looking for is not there where are you looking. 
It's like, you searching socks in you closet but you cant find the socks cause your socks aren't in the closet.

I looks like the requesting api is hosted on your localhost, maybe the api is in an ohter folder?

Comment: The API is in a different server, but I implement locally. I got the authorization code successfully. Now I want to exchange this in Access token.